# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' surrounding a while

Tags: php

I'm just having trouble figuring out why I'm getting an error at the "}" after the "$attachment_image" line, just before "". I'm probably just too tired to see it.

```
<?php if($term) {
   $args = array(
      'post_type' => 'attachment',
      'post_mime_type' => 'image',
      'posts_per_page' => 1,
      'tax_query' => array(
         array(
            'taxonomy' => 'mediacat',
            'terms' => $term->term_id,
         )
      ),
      'orderby' => 'rand',
      'post_status' => 'inherit',
   );

   $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

   while ( $loop->have_posts() ) :

   $loop->the_post();

   $item = get_the_id();

   $attachment_image = wp_get_attachment_image_url( $item, 'square' );
} ?>

<figure class="cblNavMenu--icon__imgwrap">
   <div class="navimage" style="background-image: url('<?php if($term) { echo $attachment_image; } if($menu_link){ the_permalink(); } ?>');"></div>
</figure>

<?php if($term) {
   endwhile;
   wp_reset_postdata();
} ?>

</div>

<span class="cblNavMenu--label"><?php if($term) { if($cat_label) { echo $cat_label; } else { echo $current_term_name; } } if($menu_link){ if($cat_label) { echo $cat_label; } else { the_title(); } } ?></span>
```

Comment: You're missing an `endwhile`.

Comment: It's not missing. It's part of the if($term) after <figure> Basically, the "while" statement is entirely surrounded by "if($term)" statements.

Comment: OK, but you're closing the `if() {}` *before* you close the `while() : endwhile;`, which is where the error is coming from.

Answer (score 2):

You've wrapped the opening and closing of the `while` in separate `if` statements. This is the structure of your code.

```
if( $term ) {
    // etc.
   while ( $loop->have_posts() ) :
}

// etc.

if( $term ) {
   endwhile;
}
```

This is not valid PHP. You need to structure it like this:

```
if( $term ) {
    // etc.
   while ( $loop->have_posts() ) :

   // etc.

   endwhile;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:** Ah, there's a little more to it. I didn't see the `endwhile` further on in the code. To fix the code you would have to remove the `}` from the line after `$attachment_image = wp_get_attachment_image_url( $item, 'square' );` and then replace the line `<?php if ($term) {` with `<?php`. That should work fine.

*Old post*:

After the line `$attachment_image = wp_get_attachment_image_url( $item, 'square' );`, place a line that reads `endwhile;`. This should solve your problem, which is caused by the while loop started earlier not being closed.

Comment: It's not missing. It's part of the if($term) after <figure> Basically, the "while" statement is entirely surrounded by "if($term)" statements. Tried your suggestion, but it just broke the code in a different spot.

Comment: Ah, you're right. It's still a reasonably easy fix. The second `if($term)` is technically unnecessary, I've updated my answer.